# Change web page property that's not for the current site

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript

I've tried lots of workarounds and have come up with nothing. I'm trying to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595512/javascript-csom-to-access-page-properties

But since I need a page that is not the current one, I don't have access to `_spPageContextInfo`. If it makes any difference, I'm also using a custom column that is from my content type that inherits a web-part page.

I've tried this with no luck:

```
function onListItemUpdateSucceeded() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(this.storedAddress);
var currentList   = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Site Pages');
this.currentItem  = currentList.getItemById(6); //hard coded what should be 6 which should be consistent
currentItem.set_item('CustomName', this.storedTitle);
currentItem.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSiteUpdateSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));}
```

I an error that 'CustomName' doesn't exist. I tried 'Title' as well so I don't think it's my custom column that is the issue.

Comment: The code seems fine, could you get the item by rest api in browser directly? _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items(6), you could refer the official demo code https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v%3Doffice.14)#updating-a-list-item-using-javascript